# How to stream mp4 vedio in android

Tags: android, video-streaming

How to stream `.mp4` video in android, video is from backed server. By implementing all the solution showing a message can't play this video

Comment: can you be more specific on your question?

Comment: i need play mp4 vedio in VedioView UI how can i do that

Comment: Can you share the error shown in logcat too?

Comment: `can't play this video` means that video is in unsupported codec. Either use supported video codec, or implement your own video player, which will support your codec. Please note that `mp4` is not a codec, it is just a container type.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use Exoplayer which is google's video default player.

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/android-exoplayer-starters-guide-6350433f256c  please check if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

here is a very basic, working example of exoplayer 2.8.4 to play livestream or .mp4 files. 
https://github.com/ayalus/ExoPlayer-2-Example